# How can I make catchError return a network error?

Tags: ionic-framework, rxjs, pipe

This used to work fine but throwError got deprecated, now it appears catchError is no longer returning the network errors that I used to recieve.

```
this.goToApi().subscribe(response => {

  console.log(response);

},
err => {

  console.log(err);

});



public goToApi(): any
{
  return this.apiService.makeApiCall().pipe(map((response: any) => {

    return response;
  }),
    catchError((err) => { console.log(err); return err; })
  )
}
```

just to add, this interceptor is in my api service and its showing the error fine in there...

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpErrorResponse
 } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
 import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
 import{ CustomError } from '../../utils/custom-error';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

 @Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),

        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          
          if (!window.navigator.onLine) {

            return throwError(() => new CustomError('Check your internet connection.'));
          }

          return throwError(() => error);
        })
      )
  }

 }
```

and help much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: ok I sorted it, return throwError(() => error.message);  It was returning an object and looking for a string.

Answer (score 0):

ok I sorted it, return throwError(() => error.message);  It was returning an object and looking for a string.